# Count number of unique values before a certain pattern?

Tags: r

I have a column in a data frame `df$moves` which looks like this:

```
W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5 
W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.exd5 B2.Qxd5 W3.Nc3 B3.Qa5 W4.d4 B4.Nf6 W5.Nf3 B5.c6 W6.Ne5 B6.Bf5 
W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nc6 W3.Bc4
W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nf6
W1.e4 B1.c5 W2.Nf3
```

I want to get a count of all unique values before the character "W2." appears. In the above, for example, I'd expect the count of unique values before "W2." to be `1`, being the last row only, as up until "W2." row 1 is the same as row 2 and row 3 is the same as row 4.

How should this be done?

Comment: for each row? for each column? it's a bit unclear. How should the output look like?

Comment: for the column (`df$moves` is a column). The output should just be a single number, the count of unique values before a certain string

Comment: By unique you mean only the values that appear once? Based on your description it looks like you are looking for values that appear only once. Counting the unique value results in `3` in our example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach is to extract the parts before `W2`:

```
# option 1:
vec <- substr(df$moves, 1, regexpr('W2\\.', df$moves) - 1)

# option 2:
vec <- sub('W2.*', '', df$moves)
```

and then see whether they are unique:

```
sum(!duplicated(vec) & !duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > sum(!duplicated(vec) & !duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE))
> [1] 1
> ```

What this does:

- `regexpr('W2\\.', df$moves)` extracts the positions where `W2` first appears.
- Substract `1` from those positions and feed the result to `substr`:  `substr(df$moves, 1, regexpr('W2\\.', df$moves) - 1)` then gets the parts before `W2`.
- An easier way to extract is using `sub` instead of a `substr`/`regexpr`-combo: `sub('W2.*', '', df$moves)`.
- `!duplicated(vec) & !duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)` indicates which parts of `vec` are unique.
- By wrapping that in `sum` you get the number of unique values before `W2`.

---

If you want to count the number of unique values instead of the values that only appear once, you can either do `sum(!duplicated(vec))` of `length(unique(vec))`

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(moves = c("W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5", 
                               "W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.exd5 B2.Qxd5 W3.Nc3 B3.Qa5 W4.d4 B4.Nf6 W5.Nf3 B5.c6 W6.Ne5 B6.Bf5", 
                               "W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nc6 W3.Bc4", "W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nf6", "W1.e4 B1.c5 W2.Nf3")), 
                .Names = "moves", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `strsplit` with *look-ahead* `split` argument as `split = " (?=W2\\.)"` can be as:

```
length(unique(sapply(strsplit(df$Moves, split = " (?=W2\\.)", perl = TRUE), 
                                                       function(x)x[1])))

#[1] 3

# where the unique values are:
unique(sapply(strsplit(df$Moves, split = " (?=W2\\.)", perl = TRUE),
                                                       function(x)x[1]))
#[1] "W1.e4 B1.d5" "W1.e4 B1.e5" "W1.e4 B1.c5"
```

> **Regex:**
>
> ```
> " (?=W2\\.)"  -- space followed by W2.
> ```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Moves
'W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5'
'W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.exd5 B2.Qxd5 W3.Nc3 B3.Qa5 W4.d4 B4.Nf6 W5.Nf3 B5.c6 W6.Ne5 B6.Bf5' 
'W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nc6 W3.Bc4'
'W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nf6'
'W1.e4 B1.c5 W2.Nf3'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are counting the number of apprearances of `W2` in each row, while OP wants *"unique values before the character "W2." appears"*

Comment: @Jaap You are correct. Probably, expected output was not very clear from question but additional comment has clarified it. Your añswer is most appropriate, let me see if I can find an alternative☺. Else I'll delete mine.